Mastering the inner game of bullying/harrassment
In grade school while in class, children would sometimes shoot paper darts with a rubber band at someone sitting in front of them. Often the class would end and all would be forgotten. However, if the harassment went on for a long time, the child in front would get so irritated, and they would snap and do something violent to whoever was harassing them. Of course, the teacher would only see/hear the violent reaction and would get no backstory about what led up to it. And the victim would end up looking like the bad person.
From my perspective, in addition to being angry at the person harassing them, the victim is also frustrated at themselves for losing control after being provoked. What does Buddhism have to say about this?
A victim might intellectually try to resolve their problem by saying that all is "maya", but their anger would still be real. There is still an "I" that is being harassed. When fists can't resolve the problem, what other approaches can one use?

Speak to the teacher in private about the matter.
As for "maya", IF the rubber darts are seen as "maya", there will be no anger.
Actually, there is no "I" being harassed. There is only five aggregates struck by paper darts.
The above said, this is a moral matter. Speak to the teacher in private about the matter.

+1 about speaking to the teacher. And if the teacher choose to ignore or do nothing. Relate the entire matter to the parents/guardians and ask for a transfer to a better school.

Teach your child to be fearless. Buddhism teaches one to face the adversity by looking into its eyes with courage. Compassion is not a sign of fear. If someone comes running towards you with a knife in hand to kill you, then you should not run away. Buddha has said that if somebody cuts off your limbs while you being alive then not only you shouldn’t run away but also you shouldn’t harbour any ill will or resentment or anger or cruel thoughts towards your enemy.
Compassionate and fearless action is expected out of a serious adult Buddhist practitioner.
However you can teach the child to be courageous by asking him or her to handle the situation himself by complaining to the teacher or facing the adversary head on without any violence. He can ask the bully why is he doing that without getting violent.
Basically you should teach the child to be courageous in whichever way because that’s what Buddha has taught his followers.
FACE the ADVERSARY with COMPASSION and COURAGE. No one is born with such extraordinary skills , it needs to be developed.
